# \usepackage for \newenvironment

Tags: environments, package-writing

I am trying to create a package called `lessonPlanner` in which I declare some new environments via `\newenvironment`

So I have something like

...  mwe.tex

```
\usepackage{lessonPlanner}
\begin{document}
```

.... In my file "lessonPlanner.sty" I have

```
\newenvironment{unitPlan}[1]{}Hello World{}
```

.....

But LaTeX complains that I am missing a `\begin{document}` when it tries to parse the `\newenvironment{unitPlan}` definition.

So it seems I have something wrong, I would have though that all `\newenvironment` commands would be defined in the new packages.

P.S. I am trying to build my own package for lesson planning, where the lessons formats are defined the `\usepackage{lessonPlanner}` and only the content is referred to in the LaTeX document.

Comment: It is `\usepackage`. Not `P` by `p`.

Comment: You are not giving much concrete information to work on.  The first guess can't be much more help than: your defintion of the `unitPLan` environment contains an error of some kind --- presumably one that makes LaTeX try to typeset something while still reading the `.sty` file....  You should try to provide us with a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: I think you are quite right, I created a \newenvironment command with some text in its definition. for instance \newenvironment{unitPlan}[1]{}Some text{}, thinking that the text would not be typeset untill \begin{unitPlan} was called but I dont think this is the case now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `\newenvironment{unitPlan}[1]{Hello World}{}` Your Hello World is floating free in the file so LaTeX tries to typeset it before `\begin{document}`. By the way, unless you are trying to create flat lessons, you probably mean `LessonPlanner`.

Comment: See [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172511/) for the syntax you want.

Comment: Or @Werner's answer. (But I doubt that ping will work.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, and I'm sure its important but I don't know what the difference is between using LessonPlanner and lessonPlanner as package names, or for that matter creating a flat lesson means, can you expand a little bit further for my understanding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your use of `\newenvironment` is incorrect. It should be

```
\newenvironment{<env>}[<args>][<opt arg>]
  {<begin env>}
  {<end env>}
```

If you place any content between `{<begin env>}` and `{<end env>}`, TeX will take the first token as the end (`H` in this case), leaving the rest as text that should possibly be set. And, of course, in the preamble, you cannot have this, since text is only set *after* `\begin{document}`. That gives rise to your error of "Missing `\begin{document}`".

Most likely your definition should resemble

```
\newenvironment{unitPlan}[1]
  {Hello World}% \begin{unitPlan}
  {}% \end{unitPlan}
```

Comment: Stack exchange is great!