# Creating a Problem Environment

Tags: environments

I'm trying to learn how to make new environments, namely I want to make a "problem environment" for examples of problems, and the algorithms that solve them. Optimally I would  like it to use a typewriter-like font, and have some kind of shaded box around the problem kind of like the following from Algorithms by Vazirani:
[image]

I don't really know how to approach this problem, currently I'm just looking into the `\newenvironment` command, so any input would be greatly appreciated. Optimally I'm looking for an environment that has a space for the spec, the algorithm, and the runtime analysis.

```
\documentclass{11pt}{article}
\begin{document}
\newenvironment{problem}[1][ ]{
\begin{tcolorbox}
\newcommand\given[1]{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\textbf{Given}: ##1\\ \\}
\newcommand{\goal}[1]{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\textbf{Goal}: ##1\\ \\}
\newcommand\discussion[1]{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\textbf{Discussion}: ##1\\ \\}
\newcommand\algorithm[1]{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\textbf{Algorithm}: ##1\\ \\}
\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\textbf{Problem}: #1 \\
 }{\end{tcolorbox}\par}
\begin{problem}
\given{}
\goal{}
\discussion{}
\algorithm{}
\end{problem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the general question, see [my answer on this topic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172487/i-want-to-start-learning-how-to-use-newcommand-newenvironment-and-def-any-sug/172511#172511). The only way to learn it is to play around and post a much more specific question when you get stuck. That is, you need an MWE.

Comment: I'll work on getting one up. Do you know where to look for coloring, or anything?

Comment: However, if what you really want is a solution to the specific problem, there are plenty of ready-made solutions available. Just search the site. Or look at the related questions on the right. Again, your question needs to be more specific: what have you tried? That is, you need an MWE.

Comment: There are a whole bunch of questions on this e.g. try searching for `tcolorbox`. (I'd suggest searching CTAN but you can't right now - it isn't working.)

Comment: `mdframed` if your environment needs to allow page breaks.

Comment: Adding something I worked on- suggestions on ways to make it look better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is quite broad and therefore it is not easy to answer.

But I took your MWE and changed it in a way you may want to have it.
I kept the code as near to your MWE as possible. Especially, many font settings are superfluous, but I kept them.

- I would not add a `\newcommand` inside an environment if there is no specific reason for it (e.g. dependency of environment parameters). So, I moved these commands outside.
- The options for a `tcolorbox` are given by a key-value list. I made some settings which look like in the picture you provided.

The code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\given[1]{\par\noindent\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\textbf{\sffamily Given}: #1\par\bigskip}
\newcommand{\goal}[1]{\par\noindent\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\textbf{\sffamily Goal}: #1\par\bigskip}
\newcommand\discussion[1]{\par\noindent\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\textbf{\sffamily Discussion}: #1\par\bigskip}
\newcommand\algorithm[1]{\par\noindent\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\textbf{\sffamily Algorithm}: #1\par\bigskip}

\newenvironment{problem}[1][]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,
  breakable,
  sharp corners,
  beforeafter skip=10pt,
  size=fbox,
  boxrule=0pt,
  frame hidden,
  colback=black!10
  ]
  \fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\textbf{\sffamily Problem}: #1 \par\bigskip
 }{\end{tcolorbox}\par}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[5]

  \begin{problem}[My Problem]
  \given{\lipsum[1]}
  \goal{\lipsum[2]}
  \discussion{\lipsum[3]}
  \algorithm{\lipsum[4]}
  \end{problem}

  \lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As a second step, I modified this example a little bit more to help your for your own modifications:

- I removed superfluous font settings.
- `\newenvironment` is replaced by `\newtcolorbox` which is shorter and provided some exta goodies if needed.
- Some colors are added.
- The problem title line is put into a `title` with own coloring.

The code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\given[1]{\par\noindent\textbf{\sffamily Given}: #1\par\bigskip}
\newcommand{\goal}[1]{\par\noindent\textbf{\sffamily Goal}: #1\par\bigskip}
\newcommand\discussion[1]{\par\noindent\textbf{\sffamily Discussion}: #1\par\bigskip}
\newcommand\algorithm[1]{\par\noindent\textbf{\sffamily Algorithm}: #1\par\bigskip}

\newtcolorbox{problem}[1][]{enhanced jigsaw,
  breakable,
  sharp corners,
  beforeafter skip=10pt,
  size=fbox,
  boxrule=0pt,
  frame hidden,
  colback=blue!10,
  fontupper=\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont,
  fonttitle=\sffamily,
  colbacktitle=blue!50!black,
  title={\textbf{\sffamily Problem}: #1},
  top=3pt
}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[5]

  \begin{problem}[My Problem]
  \given{\lipsum[1]}
  \goal{\lipsum[2]}
  \discussion{\lipsum[3]}
  \algorithm{\lipsum[4]}
  \end{problem}

  \lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's giving me an `unknown option` error for `many`...

Comment: @Anthony I guess your installation is outdated. You should update the `tcolorbox` package to a recent version.

Comment: @Anthony The log file will tell you the version number. There should be something like `Package: tcolorbox 2015/01/14 version 3.40 text color boxes`