# create environment that resizes content

Tags: graphics, environments, minipage

I want to create an environment that puts its content within a minipage as wide as the current page.  The environment would work as follows:

```
\begin{FitToWidth}
HELLO
\end{FitToWidth}
```

and produce a "HELLO" as wide as the textwidth of the page.

Without defining an environment, this can be done as follows:

```
\documentclass[letter,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
HELLO
}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that when I try to turn this code into an environment, LaTeX returns an error (`Package graphics Error: Division by 0`).

This is what I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
\newenvironment{FitToWidth}{
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
} {
}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `adjustbox`

```
\documentclass[letter,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{showframe}  %% just for demo
\newenvironment{FitToWidth}[1][\textwidth]{%
\begin{adjustbox}{width=#1,center}
}
{\end{adjustbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
   HELLO
\end{adjustbox}

\bigskip
\begin{FitToWidth}
  HELLO
\end{FitToWidth}

\bigskip
\begin{FitToWidth}[0.5\textwidth]
  HELLO
\end{FitToWidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using `adjustbox` rather than reinventing the wheel is a good idea.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Capture the environment contents, and then resize it. The former is the difficult part, which is causing the problem. However, it's made easy by the [`environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,environ}
\NewEnviron{FitToWidth}[1][\textwidth]{%
  \begin{center}
  \makebox[\textwidth]{resizebox{#1}{!}{\BODY}}%
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\noindent X \dotfill X

\begin{FitToWidth}
HELLO
\end{FitToWidth}

\noindent X \dotfill X

\begin{FitToWidth}[.5\textwidth]
HELLO
\end{FitToWidth}

\noindent X \dotfill X

\end{document}
```

`environ` allows you to create an environment and captures its contents in the macro `\BODY`, which you can then work with inside `\resizebox`. In your attempt you're placing content in the `\begin` part and `\end` part of `FitToWidth`, but the way TeX works is it never gets to grab it's argument that way... since the `\begin`/`\end` parts are set independent from one another.

The `center` environment provides some space above/below, while `\makebox[\textwidth]` ensures that whatever you supply for the optional argument to `FitToWidth` (default is `\textwidth`) it will not cause an overfull box.

---

Another way to do it (without `environ`) would be to capture the environment contents in a box, which you can then manipulate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox{\FTWbox}
\newenvironment{FitToWidth}[1][\textwidth]
  {% \begin{FitToWidth}[<width>]
    \gdef\FTWoptarg{#1}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\FTWbox}
  }{% \end{FitToWidth}
    \end{lrbox}%
    \begin{center}
      \makebox[\textwidth]{\resizebox{\FTWoptarg}{!}{\usebox{\FTWbox}}}%
    \end{center}
  }

\begin{document}

\noindent X \dotfill X

\begin{FitToWidth}
HELLO
\end{FitToWidth}

\noindent X \dotfill X

\begin{FitToWidth}[.5\textwidth]
HELLO
\end{FitToWidth}

\noindent X \dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question which is, what is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Here is your code:

```
\newenvironment{FitToWidth}{
  \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \begin{center}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        } {
        }
      \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{center}
}
```

This has the following syntax:

```
\newenvironment{arg1}{arg2}
```

But \newenvironment` expects 3 arguments (optionally 4 or 5):

```
\newenvironment{name of environment}{stuff to do at the beginning of the environment}{stuff to do at the end}
```

So, your code is interpreted as providing a new enviornment with the name `FitToWidth` and everything else is interpreted as code to execute before processing the environment's contents.

This means that

```
  \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \begin{center}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        } {
        }
      \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{center}
```

is processed just as it is. That is, you try to resize a box which contains nothing. Nothing has a dimension of zero. Hence, when TeX calculates things, it tries to divide by zero and bails out since it cannot do that.

[This answer (admittedly mine)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172487/i-want-to-start-learning-how-to-use-newcommand-newenvironment-and-def-any-sug/172511#172511) explains the syntax of the standard macros for creating, redefining and providing new LaTeX commands and environments.