# Allow page break in table in customized environment

Tags: environments, page-breaking, longtable, longtabu

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,enumerate}
\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{longtable,tabu} % allow page break

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex


%------------------------------------------------------------------
% define my own stuff %%
%------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\key}[1]{ #1 \index{#1} }
%------------------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{reflog}[5]
{
    \cleardoublepage
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{ \large \sffamily Reflective Log -- #1} \\[2ex]
    \begin{longtabu}{ m{0.9\textwidth} }
        \toprule \\
            { \sffamily Nature of activity: } \\[2ex]
                #3 \\[2ex]
            \hline \\
            { \sffamily What struck me as important or significant:} \\[2ex]
                #4 \\[2ex]
            \hline \\
            { \sffamily Implications for my own teaching:} \\[2ex]
                #5 \\[2ex]
            \hline \\
            { \sffamily Standards this provides evidence for:} \\[2ex]
                #2 \\[2ex]
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtabu}
    \end{center}
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{reflognew}[5]
{
    \cleardoublepage
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{ \large \sffamily Reflective Log -- #1} \\[2ex]
    \begin{longtable}{ m{0.9\textwidth} }
        \toprule \\
            { \sffamily Nature of activity: } \\[2ex]
                #3 \\[2ex]
            \hline \\
            { \sffamily What struck me as important or significant:} \\[2ex]
                #4 \\[2ex]
            \hline \\
            { \sffamily Implications for my own teaching:} \\[2ex]
                #5 \\[2ex]
            \hline \\
            { \sffamily Standards this provides evidence for:} \\[2ex]
                #2 \\[2ex]
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
    \end{center}
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------
% BEGIN Document %

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\reflog{05 July 2015}{ \key{1.4},\key{2.4},\key{A},\key{1.5} }{
    test test
}{
    test test test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test 

    test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test 

    test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test 
}{
    test test test testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest 

    testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test

    test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test 
}


\reflognew{05 July 2015}{ \key{1.4},\key{2.4},\key{A},\key{1.5} }{
    test test
}{
    test test test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test 

    test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test 

    test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test 
}{
    test test test testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest 

    testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test

    test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test 
}

\end{document}
```

I have tried both `longtable` and `longtabu`, but neither is satisfactory. `longtabu` does better than `longtable`, but it still have a big gap.

[image]

Comment: I'd urge you ***not*** to use `longtabu` or `tabu`. The author has promised a new version which with no support for backwards compatibility i.e. it will break many existing documents. Unless you do not need your code to compile in the future, this is probably not what you want.

Comment: you can only break tables between rows, not in the middle of a `m` column which is a parbox. However if this reflects your real example there is only one column, so there is no need to have any table code at all, you could just have a sequence of paragraphs which could then break naturally.

Comment: Although you are defining new environments, you are not using them as environments. When you say `\newenvironment{<env>}{<begin>}{<end>}`, you create an environment which you then use like this: `\begin{<env>} bunch of stuff \end{<env>}`. In your case the syntax would be `\begin{<env>}{<1>}{<2>}...{<5>} bunch of stuff \end{<env>}`. If what you really want is a command, use `\newcommand...`. See [my answer on this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172487/i-want-to-start-learning-how-to-use-newcommand-newenvironment-and-def-any-sug/172511#172511) for further details.

Answer (score 2):

This uses the `titlesec` package to build on David's suggestion and converts the use of `\newenvironment` to `\newcommand` since you want a command rather than an environment judging by the syntax you wish to use.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\centering\bfseries\sffamily\large}{\thesection}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\sffamily}{\theparagraph}{0pt}{\hrule}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*1.5}{*2}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{*2}{*2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\newcommand{\key}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\reflog}[5]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \section{Reflective Log -- #1}
  \paragraph{Nature of activity}
  #3
  \paragraph{What struck me as important or significant}
  #4
  \paragraph{Implications for my own teaching}
  #5
  \paragraph{Standards this provides evidence for}
  #2
  \vskip 2ex plus .3ex minus .06ex
  \hrule
}

% BEGIN Document %

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\reflog{05 July 2015}{ \key{1.4},\key{2.4},\key{A},\key{1.5} }{
    test test
}{
    test test test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test

    test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test

    test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test
}{
    test test test testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest

    testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test

    test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test  test test test
}

\end{document}
```

[image: long 'table' using sectioning commands]