# LaTeX programming Inheritance with \newcommand \newenvironment \renew... etc

Tags: macros, environments

I'd like to create (or renew) several LaTeX commands and environments, and understand how it works.  One of my new environments would be equivalent to `\begin{quotation}`.  So, imagine my `\begin{foo}` environment. I want it to inherit all the functionality of quotation environments, but would like to add a `\Writinghand` glyph and revert to `\singlespacing`.  Then at the end of the quotation text I will place a `\ding{47}` glyph at the end of the last sentence, plus revert back to my usual `\onehalfspacing` (that's actually one plus a half line spacing) after the `\end{foo}` is issued.

How would that be written? And, explain how to get `\renewenvironment` and `\renewcommand` to inherit all the functionality of the original command, because I understand "`\renew...`" basically erases the LaTeX macro, and you have to start from the beginning to add back the original functionality.  But in all my cases I just want to add extra formatting glyphs and text formatting to arguments, linespacing options for my environments.

Comment: In [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172487/i-want-to-start-learning-how-to-use-newcommand-newenvironment-and-def-any-sug/172511#172511), I provide a brief introduction to `\newcommand`, \renewcommand`, \providecommand`, \newenvironment`, \renewenvironment`, `\provideenvironment` and their starred variants. I try to use examples from packages etc. to illustrate some of them and to give some sense of the advantages and limitations of these commands. (But I do not go beyond these commands as that would be too much for one post and you'd never read to the end!)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### The fellowship of `\newenvironment` and `\renewenvironment` commands

Yes, `\renew...` will erase or redefine the previous definition (or eject an error message, if this has not been defined before.)

In many cases it's more suitable to make a wrapper environment, which does not attack the original environment.

```
\newenvironment{foo}{%
%startup code, i.e the \WritingHand and `\singlespacing`

\begin{quotation}
}{%
% end code
\ding{...}
\end{quotation}
}
```

Since environments use groups, the change of the line spacing within of `foo` is safe outside, there is no need to explicitly switch back to `\onehalfspacing`. This is true for all lengths/skips and colour settings.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\onehalfspacing
\newenvironment{foo}{%
\singlespacing
\begin{quotation}
\WritingHand

}{%
\ding{47}
\end{quotation}
}

\begin{document}
% Compare the spacing outside and inside of foo environment 

Three Rings for the Elven-kings under the sky,

Seven for the Dwarf-lords in their halls of stone,

Nine for Mortal Men doomed to die,

One for the Dark Lord on his dark throne

In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie.

One Ring to rule them all, One Ring to find them,

One Ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them

In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie.


\begin{foo}
Three Rings for the Elven-kings under the sky,

Seven for the Dwarf-lords in their halls of stone,

Nine for Mortal Men doomed to die,

One for the Dark Lord on his dark throne 

In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie. 

One Ring to rule them all, One Ring to find them, 

One Ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them 

In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie.
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**The `renewenvironment` version**

`renewenvironment` is basically similar, but one has to keep in mind too design issues:

- Should the environment be extended/improved --> use the old definition
- Completely drop the old behaviour --> do not use the old definition (of course)

I assume that the old behaviour should be available still, so I tried the first approach:

1. First store the old environment startup code, which is just the command `\quotation`, to something, say `\latex@quotation`.
2. Store the environment end code, which is `\endquotation` then, to `\latex@endquotation`.
3. Basically proceed as in the `\newenvironment` version and replace `\begin{quotation}` with `\latex@quotation` and `\end{quotation}` with `\latex@endquotation`.

The output is the same.

Important note: If the environment has optional arguments, it's better to use `\LetLtxMacro` instead of `\let`, you need the `letltxmacro` package then.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\onehalfspacing % for this document ....

\makeatletter
\let\latex@quotation\quotation
\let\latex@endquotation\endquotation

\renewenvironment{quotation}{%
\singlespacing
\latex@quotation
\WritingHand

}{%
\ding{47}
\latex@endquotation%
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
% Compare the spacing outside and inside of foo environment 

Three Rings for the Elven-kings under the sky,

Seven for the Dwarf-lords in their halls of stone,

Nine for Mortal Men doomed to die,

One for the Dark Lord on his dark throne

In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie.

One Ring to rule them all, One Ring to find them,

One Ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them

In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie.


\begin{quotation}
Three Rings for the Elven-kings under the sky,

Seven for the Dwarf-lords in their halls of stone,

Nine for Mortal Men doomed to die,

One for the Dark Lord on his dark throne

In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie.

One Ring to rule them all, One Ring to find them,

One Ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them

In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie.
\end{quotation}

% And once again

Three Rings for the Elven-kings under the sky,

Seven for the Dwarf-lords in their halls of stone,

Nine for Mortal Men doomed to die,

One for the Dark Lord on his dark throne

In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie.

One Ring to rule them all, One Ring to find them,

One Ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them

In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie.



\end{document}
```

**Edit** The shortest version: Use the `xpatch` command and its `\xpretocmd` and `\xapptocmd` macros.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\onehalfspacing % for this document ....

\newcommand{\lotrtext}{%
Three Rings for the Elven-kings under the sky,

Seven for the Dwarf-lords in their halls of stone,

Nine for Mortal Men doomed to die,

One for the Dark Lord on his dark throne

In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie.

One Ring to rule them all, One Ring to find them,

One Ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them

In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie.
}

% Append the `\singlespacing` etc. after the `\quotation` startup is called
\xapptocmd{\quotation}{\singlespacing%
\WritingHand%
}{}{}
% Prepend `\ding{47}` before `\endquotation` comes into action. 
\xpretocmd{\endquotation}{\ding{47}}{}{}

\begin{document}
% Compare the spacing outside and inside of foo environment 

\lotrtext


\begin{quotation}
\lotrtext
\end{quotation}

% And once again

\lotrtext
\end{document}
```

And the final (?) remark -- your possibilities:

- Refine a wrapper with `\newenvironment`
- Change or completely erase the previous definition with `\renewenvironment`
- Patch the commands with `\xpretocmd`, `\xapptocmd` or `\xpatchcmd` which is something between the 1st and 2nd. way.

All depends on the requested design, there is no general rule. (And if redefinition or new definition, I suggest to use `\NewDocumentEnvironment` or `\RenewDocumentEnvironment` from the very powerful `xparse` package.

Update

Mico made an important comment:

The package `etoolbox` provides the commands `\AtBeginEnvironment` and `\AtEndEnvironment`, `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `\AfterEndEnvironment` which do basically the same what I've done with `\xpretocmd` and `\xapptocmd` or the explicit `\renewenvironment`, however, to an existing environment only -- which of the `etoolbox` commands should be used depends on the precise requirements, what should be done before or after the group begins/ends.

As an alternative, there is `NewEnviron` from the `environ` package, which allows for the saving of the environment body into `\Body` macro.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Only for the quotation? ;-)

Comment: Is that a ding?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: In German language usage, everything (!!!) is a `ding` :-P

Comment: @cfr: Oh come on... only upvoting for the one ... your the second one :-P (of which I know)

Comment: +1. Very minor point: You could add a mention of the `\AtBeginEnvironment` and `\AtEndEnvironment` macros of the `etoolbox` package.

Comment: @Mico: Yes, that's a good comment. How could I forget them? I will add it and as well mention the `environ` package.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't read the rest: you're competent; I trust you.

Comment: I just thought some more about my comment and realized that `\AtBeginEnvironment` won't do the job correctly in the present case, since it inserts its code *before* the start of the `quotation` environment. Better to use `\apptocmd`, which has the same syntax as `\xapptocmd`.

Comment: @cfr ;-) ......... (filler)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/46uhg.png

Comment: @Mico: In some sense this depends on the request. You could use `\AfterEndEnvironment` and `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` then too, depending what is really needed

Comment: @cfr: Mellon ;-) You will receive another `Good Answer` badge most likely ;-)

Comment: Even with your first solution, I usually prefer to say `\quotation` … `\endquotation`, instead of `\begin{quotation}` … `\end{quotation}`, in the definition of the `foo` environment: in this way, if I mispell the name `foo` in `\end{foo}`, I get an error about an incorrectly closed `foo` environment, not about an incorrectly closed `quotation` environment. This might be important if I hand out the definition file to someone else… (+1, anyway :-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: Yes, you're right. I sometimes switch between the two possibilities.

Comment: I thought I had a typo, but keep getting a "Undefined Control Sequence error" while creating my \newenvironment as follows: "\newenvironment{\MyLetter}{\singlespacing\begin{quotation}\Writinghand}{\ding{47}\end{quotation}}"   I'm using koma script's scrbook.  Any ideas?

Comment: @user12711: `\newenvironment{MyLetter}`, not with the backslash.

Comment: @user12711: By the way: `marvosym` package defines `\WritingHand`, but uses `\let\Writinghand\WritingHand` then, so both commands are defined, `\Writinghand` just being a copy of the other one.

Comment: BINGO (it works!)

Comment: The wrapper solution may cause problems later with the customization involving counters or cooperation with other packages such as cref. You do not want to refer to the parent environment, but to the new one.

Comment: @DávidTóth: That's not the question here -- the question was of a general nature, not of counters etc.