# How do environments work?

Tags: environments, xparse

As far as I understand, when I specify

```
\newenvironment{env}{
  start
}{
  end
}
```

what LaTeX actually does is to define two macros

```
\env -> start 
\endenv -> end
```

so that

```
\begin{env}
  middle
\end{env}
```

is resolved into something like

```
{
  \env
  middle
  \endenv
}
```

---

- Is my perception correct and complete?
- Are there other things `\newenvionment`, `\begin` and `\end` do?
- Could I create the environment without `\newenvironment` just by defining `\env` and `\endenv`? Are there situation that may benefit from  this?
- Is it safe to use `\env` and `\endenv` without `\begin` and `\end`? For example, to avoid the grouping.
- How does `xparse`'s `\NewDocumentEnvironment` differ?

Many questions, all connected by one request: Please explain how environments and the related commands work.

Comment: Albeit interesting, I think this has been asked and answered elsewhere on the site.

Comment: With `xparse` you can use the parameters #1 etc. even in the end code .... and environments keep track of the current environment with `\def\@currenvir{env}` for example.

Comment: @egreg feel free to direct me there. I already searched for some variants of the question without any luck.

Comment: Somehow related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254549/latex-programming-inheritance-with-newcommand-newenvironment-renew-etc/254550#254550

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am interested in how `xparse` does these things and whether they introduce any performance penalty compared to the classic `\newenvironment`. So if you know, I would appreciate an answer.

Comment: @XZS: `xparse` does very sophisticated things, using the new LaTeX 3 language approach from `expl3`. It's not easy to explain this

Answer (score 4):

Only a partial answer:

- Environments with `\newenvironment` do in fact define `\env` and `\endenv` (if used with `env` as argument)

  However `\env...\endenv` is not group safe, see the setting of the length variable in the lower example.
- It's not possible to define `\newcommand{\otherenv}` and `\newcommand{\otherendenv}`, since this will result in an error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Command \endotherenv already defined.
>                      Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
>
> ```
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
> ```

I've asked a similar question about `\end...` macros about one year ago: [Are \end.... macro names reserved in LaTeX2e?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199692/are-end-macro-names-reserved-in-latex2e)

However, it's possible to say `\def\otherenv` and `\def\endotherenv`. This is fact how many LaTeX2e environments are defined in the LaTeX core or in packages -- for example `enumerate` is `\def\enumerate` and `\def\endenumerate` and not defined using `\newenvironment{enumerate}`

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{env}{}{}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{10pt}

\begin{document}


\begin{env}
\addtolength{\mylength}{20pt}
\end{env}

Result after: \the\mylength $\longrightarrow$ safe!

\env

\addtolength{\mylength}{20pt}

\endenv

Result after: \the\mylength $\longrightarrow$ not safe!

% Now some grouping:    
{
\env

\addtolength{\mylength}{20pt}

\endenv
}

Result after: \the\mylength $\longrightarrow$ safe again!

\end{document}
```

[image]

In addition, an environment defined with `\newenvironment` is 'self-aware' (well ;-)) -- it knows the current environment name, but only if `\begin{env}...\end{env}` is used, not with `\env...\endenv` or `{\env...\endenv}`

See the second example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ShowEnvName}{%
Current environment:  \@currenvir

}
\makeatother


\newenvironment{env}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{env}
\ShowEnvName  : Should be \texttt{env}
\end{env}

\env
\ShowEnvName  : Presumed to be \texttt{env}, but is \texttt{document}
\endenv

{
\env
\ShowEnvName  : Presumed to be \texttt{env}, but still is \texttt{document}
\endenv
}


\env
{
\ShowEnvName  : Presumed to be \texttt{env}, but still is \texttt{document}
}
\endenv


\end{document}
```

It shows the outer environment name as soon as there's no `\begin...\end` pair -- that's what `\begin...\end` do --> setting the `\@currenvir` macro.

[image]

From `latex.ltx` (or see texdoc source2e) the definition of `\begin` and `\end`:

```
\def\begin#1{%
  \@ifundefined{#1}%
    {\def\reserved@a{\@latex@error{Environment #1 undefined}\@eha}}%
    {\def\reserved@a{\def\@currenvir{#1}%
     \edef\@currenvline{\on@line}%
     \csname #1\endcsname}}%
  \@ignorefalse
  \begingroup\@endpefalse\reserved@a}
\def\end#1{%
  \csname end#1\endcsname\@checkend{#1}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\if@endpe\@doendpe\fi
  \if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi}
\def\@checkend#1{\def\reserved@a{#1}\ifx
      \reserved@a\@currenvir \else\@badend{#1}\fi}
```

`\begin` checks first whether the environment is defined at all and gives an error in the false branch. If successful, the `@currenvir` variable is set to the environment and `\csname #1\endcsname`, i.e. `\env` is called and a `\begingroup` started.

`\end` checks whether the correct environment is closed at the moment, i.e. `\begin{env}...\end{otherenv}\end{env}` would be an error if `otherenv` hasn't been opened after `env`.

Answer (score 4):

The basics of environment implementation in LaTe2e are covered in [How does LaTeX implement environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58269/how-does-latex-implement-environments). In `xparse`, the approach is slightly more complex as to allow `#1`, *etc.* in the end-of-environment code there is a dynamic definition. However, the performance hit is minimal. On top of LaTeX2e it's still necessary to set up `\foo` and `\endfoo` as that is what `\begin` and `\end` are looking for. However, the long-term vision is to provide a dedicated namespace for environment code, and `xparse` therefore includes a second 'layer' of macros for this purpose.