# how to define newcommand that takes []{} as arguments and not {}{}?

Tags: macros

I find myself doing a lot of things like this below in order to compile document for both pdf and tex4ht

```
\ifdefined\HCode
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth]{foo.eps}
\else
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth]{foo.pdf}
\fi
```

So I said to myself on a bright moment, why not write a command called `\includegraphicsX` and implement this logic inside it? So the code will look like this:

```
\includegraphicsX[width=0.5\paperwidth]{foo}
```

The problem is that  `\newcommand` only likes to accept arguments using `{}{}`, so I had to write the `\newcommand` like this: (MWE)

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\includegraphicsX}[2]
{
\ifdefined\HCode
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2.eps}
\else
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2.pdf}
\fi
}
\begin{document}
\includegraphicsX{width=0.1\paperwidth}{1_pic}
\end{document}
```

And the above works.  But I would prefer to call the command using

```
    \includegraphicsX[width=0.1\paperwidth]{1_pic}
```

and not as shown in the MWE which is

```
   \includegraphicsX{width=0.1\paperwidth}{1_pic}
```

The reason is that, if I change my mind later (and I change my mind allot) and do not want to use the macro anymore, I would then only need to remove the one letter 'X' from the call using the editor find/replace, instead of also changing the brackets around the first argument which is harder to change automatically.

Is there a trick to define a command in Latex which accepts `[]` as first argument and not as `{}` ?

Using Tl 2015

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\newcommand\commandname[2][]{<code>}` for standard `\commandname[<optional arg>]{<required arg>}` syntax.

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\includegraphicsX}[2][]
{%
\ifdefined\HCode
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2.eps}%
\else
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2.pdf}%
\fi
}
\begin{document}
\includegraphicsX[width=0.1\paperwidth]{1_pic}
\end{document}
```

[My answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172487/i-want-to-start-learning-how-to-use-newcommand-newenvironment-and-def-any-sug/172511#172511) to a more general question about creating commands and environments may be of interest.

Note that you can probably just use

```
\newcommand\includegraphicsX[2][]{%
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}}
```

which, as [Manuel points out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256546/how-to-define-newcommand-that-takes-as-arguments-and-not/256548?noredirect=1#comment614447_256548), makes `\includegraphicsX[]{}` equivalent to `\includegraphics[]{}` so you do not really need to create the new command for this use at all. If your actual definition is more complex, obviously you will still need it but can maybe use the above to simplify it somewhat.

`graphicx` can figure out appropriate extensions, depending on the engine in use etc, and it is generally better not to specify these explicitly.

Comment: maybe not *that* important for this special macro and its supposed usages but I'd remove the spurious spaces anyway.

Comment: @clemens Thanks. I copied it quickly earlier but you are quite right. I've tidied up a bit.

Comment: @cfr In your last sentence, may be you could just tell the OP to use `\includegraphics` directly :)

Comment: @Manuel True. I thought maybe the command given here was simplified for purposes of creating the MWE. If it is really just what's posted, then that is indeed an excellent point.... Edited....

Comment: `Note that you can probably just use` humm... but this does not really work for me? I need new command in order to do the `ifdefined\...\else...\fi` logic in it. I am using your first method in your answer, and it is working well as it is. thanks again.

Comment: @Nasser Indeed. I just meant that you don't need that logic for the particular example you gave because just using `\includegraphics[]{}` would do the same thing, slightly more efficiently. You may need that logic for things other than image inclusion, obviously. You just don't need it for image inclusion.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the `xparse` style of defining a command with optional argument, here with default empty optional argument.

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\NewDocumentCommand{\includegraphicsX}{O{}m}{%
  \ifdefined\HCode
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2.eps}
  \else%
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2.pdf}
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
\includegraphicsX[width=0.1\paperwidth]{1_pic}
\end{document}
```