# Latex \newcommand usage

Tags: macros, latex-base

I would like to simplify the way to type indicator functions. So I used package `bbm` and defined `\newcommand{\1}{\mathbbm{1}}`

But I actually want something like `\mathbbm{1}_{XXX}=\newcommand{1}{XXX}`. So that after I typed `\1` and I can continue to type `{XXX}` and the what comes up is `\mathbbm{1}_{XXX}`.

Comment: @I don't know how to edit this... Please help me. thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `\1{X}` to become `\mathbbm{1}_{X}`?

Comment: @egreg X means the stuff that I want to type in. For example, I want \1{x_1=x_2} defined to be \mathbbm{1}_{x_1=x_2}

Comment: Just use `\newcommand\1{\mathbbm{1}_}`

Comment: Simplest would be to type `\1_{x_1=x_2}`. One extra character, but it is clearer in the source what is intended.

Answer (score 8):

Just define `\1` with an argument:

```
\newcommand{\1}[1]{\mathbbm{1}_{#1}}
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bbm}

\newcommand{\1}[1]{\mathbbm{1}_{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\1{x_1=x_2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, the package `bbm` only provides bitmap fonts; you can get a scalable Type1 font from `bbold`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\1}[1]{\text{\usefont{U}{bbold}{m}{n}1}_{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\1{x_1=x_2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wouldn't recommend `\usepackage{bbold}`, because it clobbers the `\mathbb` font from `amssymb` (or `amsfonts`).

---

Let's stick to `\newcommand`. When you do it, you can specify a number of arguments:

```
\newcommand{\foo}[2]{...}
```

would mean `\foo` should be followed by two braced groups, the *arguments*, like

```
\foo{Abc}{def}
```

and, in the definition text, you refer to the first braced group with `#1` and to the second one by `#2`. In our case

```
\newcommand{\1}[1]{\mathbbm{1}_{#1}}
```

we just have one argument. This tells TeX that, when it finds `\1{X}`, it has to replace it with

```
\mathbbm{1}_{X}
```

The second version, with `\DeclareRobustCommand` is the same; this has the feature that, when the command `\1` is found in a section title, it's written out as such in the auxiliary file. Just a technical thing, nothing to really worry about; using `\newcommand` in the second solution would be as good.

Comment: Where can I find the instructions on how to use \newcommand. I am not able to find it online.

Comment: @DaqianSun - Any introduction to LaTeX explains how `\newcommand` is to be used. See, e.g., section 6.1.1. of the [Not so short introduction to LaTeX2e](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf).

Comment: @DaqianSun See Chapter 8 in http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html

Comment: @DaqianSun I added some basic theory about `\newcommand`.

Comment: @DaqianSun You might possibly find [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172487/i-want-to-start-learning-how-to-use-newcommand-newenvironment-and-def-any-sug/172511#172511) of interest. It explains the syntax of `\newcommand` and friends. @ egreg why not `\newcommand*`?

Comment: @cfr It adds a layer to an already hard topic for beginners.

Comment: Fair enough. I was just curious whether there was any technical reason. A pedagogical reason makes sense.