# How to define a new command?

Tags: syntax

I want to define a command that will automatically do the following:

```
\textbf{\citeasnoun{CITATION}}
```

So then I can just do:

```
\boldcite{CITATION}
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
\def \boldcite{#1} \textbf{\citeasnoun{#1}}
```

I get an error about illegal parameter number (sorry, Latex doesn't let me copy and paste the console output for some odd reason)

Comment: Welcome! What is `\citeasnoun`? It is sure not a standard command! `\newcommand*\boldcite[1]{\textbf{\citeasnoun{#1}}`. Untested as I have no clue what you're using.

Comment: See [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172487/i-want-to-start-learning-how-to-use-newcommand-newenvironment-and-def-any-sug/172511#172511) on this topic.

Comment: `\def\boldcite#1{\textbf{\citeasnoun{#1}}`

Comment: @Mark You could do that. But you shouldn't. Better to use `\newcommand*` for the reasons outlined in the answer below or my linked answer.

Comment: True.  I was trying to give the answer that minimized edit distance to the original attempted solution.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax should look like this.

```
\newcommand{\boldcite}[1]{\textbf{\citeasnoun{#1}}
```

In a `\newcommand` declaration, you use `[1]` to indicate a mandatory argument, `[2]` to indicate two arguments, and so on, and then refer to them as `#1` and `#2` in the command text.

`\newcommand` is often better than `\def`, as it will issue a warning if the command is already defined; if you know it's defined and want to overwrite it, you can use `\renewcommand` with exactly the same syntax.

Comment: That's what I said. But I wouldn't post it as an answer without knowing something about `\citeasnoun` as it might not be safe. Do you know where it is from? If so, can you complete the example?

Comment: @cfr, I don't know much about it. Searching around suggests that it's from the `harvard` package (see [here](http://tex.loria.fr/bibdex/harvard.pdf) for documentation), but I agree that _a priori_ we have no idea if this is the same package OP is using.

Comment: Yes it's from the harvard package that I use to get the right citation style: "Author (Year)"