# Missing number, treated as zero when using renewcommand

Tags: macros, margins, marginpar

I am trying to temporarily get read of marginpars in my paper.

I tried to simply `\renewcommand{\marginpar}[]{}` but I get:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>} \renewcommand{\marginpar}[]{}
```

I don't know why I am getting this error since it usually compiles my pdf without errors. Do you guys have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll want to try `\renewcommand{\marginpar}[2][]{}`. The first optional argument gives the number of arguments the (re)defined command has. If there is a second optional argument to `\(re)newcommand` the first argument of the (re)defined command is optional. You may leave out the first optional argument (it is optional after all), but if it is present it must be a number. `\marginpar` has two arguments: An optional one and a mandatory one in that order, hence `[2][]` does what you need.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117358/107497 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280527/107497 are similar questions about `\newcommand`.  `\renewcommand` has the same syntax.

Comment: @moewe that did it. Thanks for that. Please post as an answer with the explanations. Will accept right away :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get rid of `\marginpar` properly (assuming its usual definition) you will want to try

```
\renewcommand{\marginpar}[2][]{}
```

The exact syntax of `\(re)newcommand` has been explained elsewhere (for example in [\newcommand argument confusion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117358/35864)) far better than I could, so let me just recap shortly that the usual syntax for `\(re)newcommand` is

```
\newcommand{<command>}[<number of arguments>][<optional value>]{<definition>}
```

where the both arguments in square brackets are optional - if there is only one optional argument it is interpreted as the first optional argument.

`<number of arguments>` gives the number of arguments `<command>` accepts and must be a number if it is present. That is what caused the error in your example, it is not acceptable to leave the square brackets empty. If additional `<optional value>` is present, the first argument of `<command>` becomes optional and is assumed to be `<optional value>` if it is not present (optional arguments are commonly given in square brackets, mandatory arguments in curly brackets).

This means that commands defined with `\(re)newcommand` will always have one of the following argument structures

```
\foo                    % no argument at all
\foo{m_1}               % one mandatory argument
\foo[o_1]               % one optional argument
\foo{m_1}{m_2}...{m_n}  % n \leq 9, two to nine mandatory arguments
\foo[o_1]{m_1}...{m_n}  % n \leq 8, one optional argument and one to eight mandatory arguments
```

Other argument structures are possible in (La)TeX, but they have to be coded differently. Ironically, `\newcommand` itself uses a very different structure.

`\marginpar` has the following argument specification

```
\marginpar[<LTEXT>]{<RTEXT>}
```

which means that its structure can be redefined with `\renewcommand` directly as a macro with two arguments of which the first is optional.

---

[Ulrich Diez](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/118714/ulrich-diez) made a good point in the comments that one needs to be careful about the spacing. The default definition of `\marginpar` uses `\@bsphack...\@esphack` to avoid unwanted white space, see [How to make a command completely empty / invisible / non-existent?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201817/35864). If you want to replicate that behaviour to not change spacing when you disable `\marginpar`, you'll need the more involved

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\marginpar}[2][]{\@bsphack\@esphack}
\makeatother
```

Whether or not that is necessary will depend on how exactly you used `\marginpar` and what your requirements and intentions are for disabling it. If it's just for a quick test you needn't bother, if it's for the final print version that's a different matter.

Comment: Thanks for the recap. Very nice answer. Answer accepted!

Comment: @UlrichDiez Ah yes, thanks for the hint. Added a short edit.