# Why isn't my table properly aligned?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

The `\dots` doesn't seem to align properly in my table. Can anyone explain what's going on and how I can resolve this? MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
    0 \\
    \dots \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This displays like this: (red line added)

[image: Alignment issue]

Comment: Please always provide a proper minimal example and not a mere fragment of code, a code which we can compile is much more useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *is* aligned correctly. If you draw boxes around the characters with `\fbox{}` you can see what is happening:

[image: alignment]

`latex.ltx` defines `\dots` to be equivalent to `\textellipsis` in text mode and that command is defined as follows:

```
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textellipsis}{%
   .\kern\fontdimen3\font
   .\kern\fontdimen3\font
   .\kern\fontdimen3\font}
```

So the additional space on the right is the third kern following the third dot, but there is, of course, no corresponding space on the left. So, as the box around the characters shows, the tabular is aligning the rows centre. It is just that the centre of `\dots` is ***not*** the centre of the middle dot but somewhere between that dot and the third one.

If you wish, you can adjust the spacing either by adding space on the left or adding negative space on the right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
  \fbox{0}\\
  \fbox{\kern\fontdimen3\font\dots}\\
  \fbox{\dots\kern-\fontdimen3\font}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: centred dots]

## EDIT

If you wish, yes, you can create a command for this. For example:

```
\newcommand*\origkernlessdots{\dots\kern-\fontdimen3\font}
```

and then you can write

```
\begin{tabular}{c}
  \fbox{0}\\
  \fbox{\kern\fontdimen3\font\dots}\\
  \fbox{\dots\kern-\fontdimen3\font}\\
  \fbox{\origkernlessdots}\\
\end{tabular}
```

to produce

[image: more kernless dots]

But, egreg's suggestion is simpler:

\newcommand*\kernlessdots{\dots\unkern}

and then

```
\begin{tabular}{c}
  \fbox{0}\\
  \fbox{\kern\fontdimen3\font\dots}\\
  \fbox{\dots\kern-\fontdimen3\font}\\
  \fbox{\origkernlessdots}\\
  \fbox{\kernlessdots}\\
\end{tabular}
```

shows that `\kernlessdots` produces the same results as `\origkernlessdots` with simpler and more transparent code

[image: simpler kernless dots]

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I deleted my comment as the issue turned out to be a display problem in my pdf-viewer, and the code itself was fine.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer anyway. Glad it worked out ;).

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated. :) Could you clarify what the difference is between ````\newcommand*\cmd{def}```` and ````\newcommand{\cmd}{def}````?

Comment: If you define a command so it takes arguments, then if it is started, all the arguments have to be 'short' (no paragraph breaks), otherwise they can be long (paragraph breaks). It is better to use the star if you are sure you don't need long arguments. Here, we don't have any arguments at all so we certainly don't need long ones. Hence the star.

Comment: You might find [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172487/i-want-to-start-learning-how-to-use-newcommand-newenvironment-and-def-any-sug/172511#172511) helpful. It explains the syntax in more detail.

Comment: @cfr You might try `\newcommand*\kernlessdots{\dots\unkern}`

Comment: @egreg I like the simplicity of the ````\unkern```` command.