# Change font type in all tables

Tags: fonts

I want to make the font type of a table to be the same that I am using in the text, how do I do that? I am using Roboto Slab Light in the text but in the tables and captions the font is the Roboto Slab.

Here is an example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[rm,light]{roboto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{example}
\date{September 2018}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Text text text.

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
       text  & text \\
       text  & text
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Normally tables are set in the same font as the surounding text. Could you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrated your problem?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could add `\mdseries` to your table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[rm,light]{roboto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
Text text text.

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering\mdseries
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
       text  & text \\
       text  & text
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

***EDIT**

to automatically apply this to all tables, you can use the @egreg's nice solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286772/36296

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[rm,light]{roboto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\appto\@floatboxreset{%
  \ifx\@captype\andy@table
    \mdseries
  \fi
}
\def\andy@table{table}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
Text text text.

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
       text  & text \\
       text  & text
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That works! But is there a way to make it in the main.tex  so I don't have to change it every time?

Comment: @Marina You could try the following trick: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2594/36296

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: @Marina Please see my edit