# Examples of table of contents in pure TeX

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, tex-core, plain-tex

I'd like to try to create a document structure and table of contents in pure TeX. Does anyone know of any resources or examples to do this? My purpose is mainly educational, to learn how to write macros and structure documents in pure TeX.

I know how to define basic commands using `\def`, and I've written documents in plain TeX but I don't understand enough about programming in TeX to feel able to tackle a big task like this.

Comment: You may want to have a look at `eplain.tex`

Comment: [this wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros) may help, here is the link for the file that egreg mentionned [eplain.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/eplain/tex/eplain.tex)

Comment: For a wide [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12668/92620) about programming on Latex. About [defining new commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172487/92620)

Comment: eplain.tex looks very interesting to learn from, and thanks for the link to it as well. I'm trying to work using just core TeX (I'm weird like that :) ), so the more specifically LaTeX oriented stuff is less useful.

Comment: The TeX Book, of course, and the source of the TeX Book. (Not the bits which rely on the `plain` format already being defined, but the bits about the primitives and the defining of that format etc.) But this is presumably obvious.

Comment: The ability to see the obvious is often considered the truest mark of genius. Thank you.

Comment: if you'd like to look at a perhaps rather unconventional collection of tables of contents prepared with plain tex, you can look at the tugboat contents.  (much of tugboat is now set with latex, but the contents, front matter and calendar are still "plain only".)  you can see the typeset contents as part of each issue, linked from http://tug.org/TUGboat , and the input for the contents can be found at ctan; go to http://ctan.org/search and search for "tugboat".  these contents files are compiled by hand (it's possible to automate, but easier manual),  if questions, please ask.

Comment: I'm sure that OPmac has this type of functionality, and it is I believe written in plain TeX http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-e.html

Answer (score 9):

If you are willing to use a macro package for that, I can recommend the compact `opmac` macros.  They provide access to a multitude of LaTeX's features in a simple manner.

```
\input opmac
\maketoc
\sec Hello World
\bye
```

[image]

If you want to implement it on your own, you can just look at [`opmac.tex`](http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/opmac/opmac.tex) to get inspiration.  The source is very readable and easy to understand.