# How to fix sizes between different fonts

Tags: fontsize, scaling, math-fonts

**actual problem:**

How to make a second font the same "actual" size of the first one.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\afont}{\fontsize{14}{48}\itshape\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texta}{\afont}
\newcommand*{\bfont}{\fontsize{21}{48}\itshape\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textb}{\bfont}
\newcommand*{\cfont}{\fontsize{30}{48}\itshape\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textc}{\cfont}

\newcommand{\printa}[1]{\texta{#1}}
\newcommand{\printb}[1]{\textb{#1}}
\newcommand{\printc}[1]{\textc{#1}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\matha}{\printa{SPEZIAL}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mathb}{\printb{SPEZIAL}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mathc}{\printc{SPEZIAL}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mathd}{\printd{SPEZIAL}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
This Is A Great Sentence With A $\matha$ Word.\\
{\Large This Is A Great Sentence With A $\mathb$ Word.}\\
{\Huge This Is A Great Sentence With A $\mathc$ Word.}\\
\\
SPEZIAL=14 rest=12 difference=2\\
SPEZIAL=21 rest=17 difference=4\\
SPEZIAL=30 rest=25 difference=5
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to define normalsize, large, Large, ... of the second font to fit to the rest of the text?

---

I'm using two different fonts in one document.

**Short form:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\myfont}{\itshape\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textmy}{\myfont}

\newcommand{\printmy}[1]{\textmy{#1}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\mathmy}{\printmy{SPEZIAL}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
This Is A Great Sentence With A $\mathmy$ Word.\\
This Is A Great Sentence With A {\large $\mathmy$} Word.\\ %bad fix
{\large This Is A Great Sentence With A $\mathmy$ Word.}
\end{document}
```

The SPEZIAL word doesn't use the right size.

---

**Long form:**

Here a (not really) MWE, but a test document with different sizes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\nofont}{\itshape\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textno}{\nofont}
\newcommand*{\largefont}{\large\itshape\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlarge}{\largefont}
\newcommand*{\afont}{\fontsize{12}{90}\itshape\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texta}{\afont}
\newcommand*{\bfont}{\fontsize{12}{1}\itshape\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textb}{\bfont}
\newcommand*{\cfont}{\fontsize{12}{200}\itshape\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textc}{\cfont}
\newcommand*{\dfont}{\fontsize{12}{48}\itshape\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textd}{\dfont}
\newcommand*{\efont}{\fontsize{13}{48}\itshape\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texte}{\efont}
\newcommand*{\ffont}{\fontsize{14}{48}\itshape\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textf}{\ffont}
\newcommand*{\gfont}{\fontsize{15}{48}\itshape\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textg}{\gfont}
\newcommand*{\hfont}{\fontsize{16}{48}\itshape\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texth}{\hfont}

\newcommand{\printno}[1]{\textno{#1}}
\newcommand{\printlarge}[1]{\textlarge{#1}}
\newcommand{\printa}[1]{\texta{#1}}
\newcommand{\printb}[1]{\textb{#1}}
\newcommand{\printc}[1]{\textc{#1}}
\newcommand{\printd}[1]{\textd{#1}}
\newcommand{\printe}[1]{\texte{#1}}
\newcommand{\printf}[1]{\textf{#1}}
\newcommand{\printg}[1]{\textg{#1}}
\newcommand{\printh}[1]{\texth{#1}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\mathno}{\printno{SPEZIAL}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mathlarge}{\printlarge{SPEZIAL}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\matha}{\printa{SPEZIAL}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mathb}{\printb{SPEZIAL}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mathc}{\printc{SPEZIAL}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mathd}{\printd{SPEZIAL}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mathe}{\printe{SPEZIAL}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mathf}{\printf{SPEZIAL}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mathg}{\printg{SPEZIAL}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mathh}{\printh{SPEZIAL}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
This Is A Great Sentence With A $\mathno$ Word.

This Is A Great Sentence With A $\mathlarge$ Word. I guess this is the right size.

{\large This Is A Great Sentence With A $\mathlarge$ Word. Doesn't grow.}

This Is A Great Sentence With A $\matha$ Word.

This Is A Great Sentence With A $\mathb$ Word.

This Is A Great Sentence With A $\mathc$ Word.

This Is A Great Sentence With A $\mathd$ Word.

This Is A Great Sentence With A $\mathe$ Word.

This Is A Great Sentence With A $\mathf$ Word. I guess this is the right size, too.

{\large This Is A Great Sentence With A $\mathf$ Word. Doesn't grow.}

This Is A Great Sentence With A $\mathg$ Word.

This Is A Great Sentence With A $\mathh$ Word.
\end{document}
```

Somehow I think, that the first variant is to small. So I tried to enlarge it (in the correct way).

---

My result so far is that I found two solutions, but they do not grow with the rest of the text.

Open questions:

1. Is the second solution "more correct" than the first? Equal? First is better?
2. How to let both fonts grow simultaneously
3. The second argument of fontsize has no effect. (I guess this is may only be in my example) What is the "default" value? / Which value should I use (even if it doesn't matter)

---

Comment: `\itshape` is only used, because `qzc`isn't available in upshape

Comment: Because it shouldn't in my point of view. `\DeclareMathOperator{\wombat}{\fontfamily{qzc}\mathit{Wombat}}`

Comment: this doesn't work. qzc is ignored in your solution. Only `mathit` is used.

Why am I using qzc: SPEZIAL is actual a mathematical class. There are more classes of this type and I think that highlighting them is a good idea

Comment: You are right, i haven't even noticed. `\DeclareMathOperator{\wombat}{\text{\fontfamily{qzc}\itshape {Wombat}}}` But it gets weirder by the minute. Maybe a more experience math and font user can help you better. Please update the question with the latest news, so it gets back on top of the main site.

Comment: Your last solution has the same effects as my codelines 8-9, 29, 40. even though your solution is shorter, I find my one better/cleaner, because it also allows to use `\textno{SPEZIAL}` analogous to `\texttt{SPEZIAL}` and so on...

Comment: `\normalsize` will give `12pt` for all fonts in the document. However, `pt` is a font-relative unit: how large `1pt` is depends on the font. Hence, `12pt` in one font may be larger or smaller than `12pt` in another. This is why combinations of different fonts often scale one font to match the size of the other.

Comment: You redesigned the question after accepting an answer. That is not logical. If the answer ansered your question, that's good. If you have a follow up, ask a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Font sizes are not standardised in the relevant sense. `pt` in this context is not the standard `pt` TeX gives you if you ask it to skip a `pt` to the right or draw a rule so many `pt`s thick or whatever.

When thinking about font sizes, the size of a `pt` depends on the font. Hence, `12pt` is a font-relative size. `\normalsize` is `12pt` for every font in your example, but `12pt` is not the same.

To see this, try

```
\documentclass[border=0pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
% \usepackage{lmodern}% 3mm x 3mm
% \usepackage{venturis}% 2mm x 2mm
\usepackage[scale=1]{tgchorus}% 2mm x 2mm
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]
  \node [draw] {X};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Uncommenting the different packages results in a PDF of different sizes. Some are 2mm high; some 3mm.

This is why fonts which are not originally designed to work together typically require scaling in order to create a good result. Some fonts, including Chorus are installed with scaling in mind. In these cases, it is easy to scale the font to match other fonts in the document.

I guess that you want something like this:

```
{\tiny This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\scriptsize This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word. I guess this is the right size.\par}

{\footnotesize This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\small This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\normalsize This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\large This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\Large This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\LARGE This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word. I guess this is the right size, too.\par}

{\Huge This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word. Doesn't grow.\par}

This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.
```

to produce this:

[image: scaled Chorus to match Latin Modern]

or this:

```
{\tiny This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\scriptsize This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word. I guess this is the right size.\par}

{\footnotesize This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\small This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\normalsize This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\large This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\Large This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\LARGE This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word. I guess this is the right size, too.\par}

{\Huge This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word. Doesn't grow.\par}

This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.
```

to produce this:

[image: scaling Chorus in text and maths mode]

I did this by scaling Chorus using

```
\newcommand*\qzc@scale{1.2}
```

My font configuration for Chorus looks like this

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\qzcstyle{%
  \fontencoding{T1}%
  \fontseries{m}%
  \fontshape{it}%
  \fontfamily{qzc}%
  \selectfont
}
```

for the basic command and

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand\qzctext{%
  \qzcstyle
}
```

for the text command.

For convenience, I defined

```
\newcommand*\textqzc[1]{\text{\qzctext{#1}}}
```

for use in maths mode and

```
\newcommand*\spezial{\textqzc{SPEZIAL}}
```

for testing.

Note that `\text{}` is doing important work in maths mode because it invokes `\mathchoice` to control the size and spacing of the mathematical atom in relation to other atoms.

Compare the two versions. The first is typeset with `\textqzc`, which uses `\text{\qzctext{}}`:

```
\[
  \sum_{\textqzc{i}=1}^n \frac{\textqzc{a}^2 + 3^{\textqzc{b}}}{\textqzc{ab}^2 + n^{\textqzc{a}}}
\]
```

and second simply uses `\qzctext{}` directly:

```
\[
  \sum_{\qzctext{i}=1}^n \frac{\qzctext{a}^2 + 3^{\qzctext{b}}}{\qzctext{ab}^2 + n^{\qzctext{a}}}
\]
```

Here's the result:

[image: comparison: with and without \text]

As can be seen, the spacing in the second version is incorrect because `\qzctext{}` is a text font command and does not make appropriate allowances for spacing in maths mode. The first version, using `\text{}` invokes `\mathchoice` to make the required adjustments and the spacing is correct.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\qzc@scale{1.2}
\DeclareRobustCommand\qzcstyle{%
  \fontencoding{T1}%
  \fontseries{m}%
  \fontshape{it}%
  \fontfamily{qzc}%
  \selectfont
}
\makeatother
\DeclareTextFontCommand\qzctext{%
  \qzcstyle
}
\newcommand*\textqzc[1]{\text{\qzctext{#1}}}
\newcommand*\spezial{\textqzc{SPEZIAL}}

\begin{document}

% scaled Chorus in maths mode using \text{}

{\tiny This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\scriptsize This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word. I guess this is the right size.\par}

{\footnotesize This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\small This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\normalsize This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\large This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\Large This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\LARGE This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word. I guess this is the right size, too.\par}

{\Huge This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word. Doesn't grow.\par}

This Is A Great Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.

% scaled Chorus in text and maths modes

{\tiny This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\scriptsize This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word. I guess this is the right size.\par}

{\footnotesize This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\small This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\normalsize This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\large This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\Large This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.\par}

{\LARGE This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word. I guess this is the right size, too.\par}

{\Huge This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word. Doesn't grow.\par}

This Is A \qzctext{Great} Sentence With A $\spezial$ Word.
\end{document}
```

Comment: comment/question: wouldn't be `\newcommand*\textqzc[1]{\qzctext{#1}}` instead of `\newcommand*\textqzc[1]{\text{\qzctext{#1}}}` cleaner. The second one produces minimal more whitespace

Comment: `\qzctex{#1}` will not work. `\qzctext{#1}` will work.

Comment: See also [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172487/i-want-to-start-learning-how-to-use-newcommand-newenvironment-and-def-any-sug/172511#172511) regarding `\newcommand` and friends. (Possibly helpful. Then again, possibly not.) That definition of `\spezial` is identical to the one I gave. Are you talking about using `\newcommand*\spezial{\qzctext{SPEZIAL}}`?

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks. Fairly recently, I guess. I forget exactly. It is in the chat transcript if you want to know badly enough, though I can't imagine why you would ;).

Comment: @Ben  If you have a follow up, ask a new question.

Comment: @Ben I think deleting comments which are off-topic or have been addressed (e.g. problems caused by typos) or which the answer has been edited to accommodate can generally be deleted to good effect.